# Spacing different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Here is a link to the page that is giving me trouble:

http://youtube.thegoblin.net/layoutfix/

If you view the website in firefox and chrome you can see that the spacing is different. The way it looks in chrome is the way I meant it to look.

I have tried linking in the YUI 2: Reset CSS as it as suggested in another question, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here's the stylesheet link: http://youtube.thegoblin.net/layoutfix/styles/style.css

Comment: all browsers render differently.

Comment: yes but how do I combat this? Other sites do not have different spacing in different browsers, so they must have done something to fix it.

Comment: You combat this by making sure your code follows the W3C HTML spec.  [You have misplaced tags and a duplicate `id`](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.thegoblin.net%2Flayoutfix%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change line-height on some elements that contains text. These are line-heights for some (maybe all) elements you need to change:

```
#title: 56px
.yoText: 46px
#buttonTitle: 68px
#buttonText: 34px
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like browsers count differently line height for font you choose, so defiantly `line-height` could make it better.

Just short example, not full fix:

```
#dl-button #buttonTitle {
   color: #37590B;
   float: right;
   font-family: "TallDark";
   font-size: 600%;
   line-height: 0.7;
   margin-right: 60px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px #BDF277;
}
```

makes green button much better, so you may play around with others the same way.

Comment: Ok I found a solution, its a bit hacky, but it seems to work for me, I added @-moz-document url-prefix() to the style sheet and made some adjustments that would only show up in firefox, and readjusted the line height and it seems to work ok for me now.

Comment: @ρσݥzση, you have some [serious issues with your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.thegoblin.net%2Flayoutfix%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Fix those first and you might not need any CSS "hacks".